# jScrollPane remove horizontal pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery with pictures in a li.
the li is set to overflow hidden so the images don't seem large.
but when i put the scrollpane on the div gallery it puts a horizontal pane on which it's shouldn't
So how do i remove the horizontal pane?

Comment: Hi, to get interest in your question, and of course good answers, consider linking to examples. Either a live on your domain or a just-the-problem exampleon jsfiddle.net will do. Also link to the resources you're using, not everyone knows what jScrollPane is and how it works :)